# Can I see two vertex group at the same time while weight painting?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights, vertex-paint

I just Wanted To See two Different Vertex groups at the same time so thatwhen i am weight painting i do not overlap each other

Comment: No, but if you turn on masking, you can hide any part of the mesh.